# I can't get value correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm newbie. Please help me. I can't get the true value of black cube.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div style="background-color:blue;" class="color-item"></div>
<div style="background-color:black;" class="color-item"></div>
<style>
  .color-item {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
  }
</style>
<script>
  $('.color-item').click(function() {
    var color = $('.color-item').css('background-color');
    console.log(color.toString());
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What you want please shared more details which value you want?

Comment: Inside the click handler change`$('.color-item')` to `$(this)`. Also note that `css()` returns a string so `toString()` is redundant.

Comment: What you want based on CSS you want value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use $(this) instead of $('.color-item') in body of your function :

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div style="background-color:blue;" class="color-item"></div>
<div style="background-color:black;" class="color-item"></div>
<style>
  .color-item {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
  }
</style>
<script>
  $('.color-item').click(function() {
    var color = $(this).css('background-color');
    console.log(color.toString());
  });
</script>
</html>
```